# IOS Keyboard suggestion bar on top of content

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface

For my course with RMIT I'm running through the 'App Development With Swift' book and am now working on scrolling views.

I implemented the code the book told me to to make the scroll view move out of the way of the keyboard but it's not noticing the suggestion bar on top of the keyboard and so [this happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COdxE.png) which is definitely not ideal as it is the phone number field I'm attempting to input text into.

The code I'm using for this is as follows

```
    func registerForKeyboardNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWasShown(_:)),name: .UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillBeHidden(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWasShown(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    guard let info = notification.userInfo,
        let keyboardFrameValue = info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue
        else {return}
    let keyboardFrame = keyboardFrameValue.cgRectValue
    let keyboardSize = keyboardFrame.size

    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize.height, 0.0)
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
}

@objc func keyboardWillBeHidden(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
}
```

I'm wondering if this code was written before the suggestion bar existed and if there's a new way to do it that includes the suggestion bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this key `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` with `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`